# Getting values (id, purchaseOrderNumber and amount) from the PDF file in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, pdftotext

I am trying to fetch the values from the uploaded pdf file. So when the file is successfully uploaded, I want to get some data specifically, ID, PurchaseOrderNo, and Amount from this PDF file.

So far, I have approached [spatie/pdf-to-text](https://github.com/spatie/pdf-to-text#requirements) and I am able to upload and open the PDF file but I am not able to and I dont know how can I fetch the required data and display it on my Blade View.

```
$name=$file->getClientOriginalName();
$file->move(public_path().'/pdftotext/', $name);
$data[] = $name;
$attachments = public_path().'/pdftotext/'. $name;


$path = public_path('/pdftotext/'. $name);
$text =  Pdf::getText ('Invoice 56569.pdf', $path);
```

The above code will upload the pdf file and store it inside public/pdftotext folder and after uploading it will open the uploaded pdf file but it will not fetch any values.

Please advice me how can I fix this. Thanks for your time.

Comment: the second argument is the path to the pdftotext binary not the pdf save folder path, it should be just `Pdf::getText($path)`.. all in the docs

Comment: Why not `$text =  Pdf::getText ($name);`  the `$path` var is undefined.  But it seems like a good time to change this `$file->move(public_path().'/pdftotext/', $name);` to `$file->move($path, $name);` and above that `$path = public_path().'/pdftotext/';` then you can clean all that up.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone i am not sure, but its working for me. I was being trying this since last week and i managed to solved it. When I upload the file, the files gets uploaded to the folder and it opens the pdf file in the browser.

Comment: it gets an error: `The command ""/usr/bin/pdftotext" "Invoice 56569.pdf" -" failed. Exit Code: 1(General error) Working directory: `

Comment: if we want to use the custom path, it says on the Spatie website `echo Pdf::getText('book.pdf', '/custom/path/to/pdftotext');`

Comment: You should define `$path` much earlier, and then use it instead of all these `public_path().'/pdftotext/'` calls,  also there is difference with that and `$path = public_path('/pdftotext/'. $name)`.  So it would clean all that up and make it much nicer to read.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```
   $name=$file->getClientOriginalName();
   $file->move(public_path().'/pdftotext/', $name);
   $data[] = $name;
   $attachments = public_path().'/pdftotext/'. $name;


   $path = public_path('/pdftotext/'. $name);
   $text =  Pdf::getText ('Invoice 56569.pdf', $path);
```

It makes more sense to do this:

```
   $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
   $path = public_path('/pdftotext/');
   $file->move($path, $name);
   $text =  Pdf::getText ($name, $path); 

   // -- these have no bearing on this code so do them a bit later (here I will just ignore them)
   //$data[] = $name;  
   //$attachments = $path.$name;
```

While this may not "solve" your issue, it was to much to post in a comment, and it will make it much cleaner, less buggy, and more pleasant to read.

I am not a very organized person, but lack of organization in code will cause you more problems then most anything else.

The most important thing in the code I posted above is a change to this:

```
 $path = public_path('/pdftotext/');
```

Instead of what you originally had  (with the filename)

```
 $path = public_path('/pdftotext/'. $name);
```

Rather or not this is the "problem" depends on how they implement `Pdf::getText` they could use `dirname()` on the second argument which would be fine then as that will return the folder name {minus} - the filename.  But if they check `is_dir()` on that it will fail.

After moving things around this became clear to me by how this was used.

```
  $path = public_path('/pdftotext/'.$name);
  $file->move($path, $name);  ///file->move(pdftotext/book.pdf, book.pdf) etc...
```

Which didn't seem right to me.  Further this would make your call to `Pdf::getText` to be this (for example)

```
  echo Pdf::getText('book.pdf', '/custom/path/to/pdftotext/book.pdf');
```

When what you probably want is this:

```
 echo Pdf::getText('book.pdf', '/custom/path/to/pdftotext/');
```

Which is why I said above that it depends on how they implement `Pdf::getText` because there are ways to tell if a path is a DIR or a FILE.  So they could work around this inside that method.  I have no idea if they do (maybe I will look a the source and see).  I looked {briefly} and it doesn't appear they check it at all.

Make sense.  This is why I said to organize it as things become more clear the easier it is to read the code.

Comment: hey, i am still getting an error based on the code u provided. The error is `Unable to create the "C:\xampp\htdocs\assignment_Sem2\public\pdftotext/Invoice 56569.pdf" directory

Comment: The issue is the aforementioned second argument, have a look at the docs, https://github.com/spatie/pdf-to-text#usage

Comment: this line `$path = public_path('/pdftotext/'. $name);`  should not include the filename, likely the cause of all your issues.  I updated the answer.

Comment: yes I read that, but what you had (see my last comment) was this `echo Pdf::getText('book.pdf', '/custom/path/to/pdftotext/book.pdf');`  With the filename as part of the second argument...  In theory they should be using `dirname()` on that second argument, but I have no idea if they do that.  If they just do something like `is_dir()` on it it would be incorrect.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix still there is an error. I removed and followed the code. The error i am getting is: `The command ""C:\xampp\htdocs\assignment_Sem2\public\pdftotext/" "Invoice 56569.pdf" -" failed. Exit Code: 1(General error) Working directory: C:\xampp\htdocs\assignment_Sem2\public Output: ================ Error Output: ================ '"C:\xampp\htdocs\assignment_Sem2\public\pdftotext/"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. `

Comment: @LawrenceCherone anyways, I have managed to open the PDF file but my main problem is stated in this question, How can i get the values from this PDF file ?

Comment: @SarahMalik - for that you will have to look at what there documentation says.  it looks like this may just convert the PDF to text as a whole.